# Cannot create azure pipeline variable using task.setvariable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I've been trying to set policy for managed service identities for my key vault, but I haven't been able to create needed variable in my yml. According to the pipeline output the variable 'indentity' in the below code gets populated, but the variable WEB_APP_MANAGED_IDENTITY doesn't. Thus the last task "Add set policy for function app" naturally fails. What can I be doing incorrectly ?

```
parameters:
  serviceConnector: ''
  appResourceGroupName: ''
  appName: ''
  appPlan: ''
  appInsightsName: ''
  location: ''
  planSkuName: ''
  PostgresServerName: ''
  AdminUserName: ''
  AdminPassWord: ''
  pgSkuName: ''
  subscriptionId: ''
  keyVaultName: ''
  devOpsServicePrincipalObjectId: ''
  verkkoGroupServicePrincipalObjectId: ''

stages:

  - stage: 'CREATE_SERVICE_APP'
    displayName: 'Create Osakeekstra service app'
    jobs:
      - job:

        steps:
          - checkout: none

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Create and configure web app'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(serviceConnector)'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              scriptType: 'bash'
              failOnStandardError: false
              inlineScript: |
                echo ">>>> Create app service plan"
                az appservice plan create \
                  --name $(appPlan) \
                  --resource-group $(appResourceGroupName) \
                  --location $(location) \
                  --sku $(planSkuName) \
                  --is-linux 2>/dev/null

                # create web app
                echo ">>>> Create web app"
                az webapp create \
                  --resource-group $(appResourceGroupName) \
                  --name $(appName) \
                  --runtime "Python|3.7" \
                  --plan $(appPlan) 
                  

                # enable managed identity
                echo ">>>> Enable managed identity"
                identity=`az webapp identity assign \
                  --name $(appName) \
                  --resource-group $(appResourceGroupName) \
                  --query principalId -o tsv`
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=WEB_APP_MANAGED_IDENTITY]$identity"
                  echo $WEB_APP_MANAGED_IDENTITY
                  echo $identity
                  echo ">>>> Enabled managed identity"
                  
           
          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Create key vault'
            inputs:
              scriptType: bash
              azureSubscription: '$(serviceConnector)'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                echo ">>>> Create key vault"
                az keyvault create \
                  --name $(keyVaultName) \
                  --resource-group $(appResourceGroupName) \
                  --location $(location) \
                  --no-self-perms \
                  --sku standard \
                  --enable-soft-delete true \
                  2>&1

                # add set policy for managed service identities
                echo ">>>> Add set policy for function app"
                az keyvault set-policy \
                  --name $(keyVaultName) \
                  --secret-permissions get \
                  --object-id $(FUNCTION_APP_MANAGED_IDENTITY)

              failOnStandardError: true
```

Whwn I changed the last command to this

```
        # enable managed identity
        echo ">>>> Enable managed identity"
        identity=`az webapp identity assign \
          --name $(appName) \
          --resource-group $(appResourceGroupName) \
          --query principalId -o tsv`

        # add set policy for managed service identities
        echo ">>>> Add set policy for function app"
        az keyvault set-policy \
          --name $(keyVaultName) \
          --secret-permissions get \
          --object-id $(indentity)
```

I got errors :  indentity: command not found
ERROR: argument --object-id: expected one argument

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here that I can see.

First, if memory serves, `az webapp identity assign` will return more then just the `principalId`, so you'll need to parse apart the result to get the correct value.

Second, to reference `identity` as a ***release*** variable (using macro syntax `$(variablename)`) instead of an environment variable, you need to add `;isOutput=true` inside the `task.setvariable` statement, as in `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=identity;isOutput=true]$identity"` - so you're setting the release variable named `identity` to the value of then environment variable named `identity`.

Third, in your reference to `identity` in the following task, `identity` is misspelled as `indentity`.

Fourth, and this is least important, you do `echo $WEB_APP_MANAGED_IDENTITY` after the `task.setvariable` command - it's not available then - `task.setvariable` is a "marker" that Azure Pipelines uses to scrape the console output, and then use to set variables for subsequent tasks and jobs.

You can either set the variable as `##vso[task.setvariable variable=identity;isOutput=true]$identity` and refer to it later as `$(identity)`, or, using your original name, set the variable as `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=WEB_APP_MANAGED_IDENTITY;isOutput=true]$identity"` and refer to it later as `$(WEB_APP_MANAGED_IDENTITY)`

Comment: I didn't manage using the instructions above, but I finally got it working using my alternative (identity assign and set policy in the same task) after fixing --object-id $(indentity) to --object-id $identity. Thanks for your hints !